# Issues in editing a Joomla plugin, cannot find files

Tags: file, joomla, edit, contact-form

I am unable to find this page in the Joomla files. I want to edit this table and place a link in every row in the table. This is a creative contact form plugin for Joomla.

The page link from the Joomla administrator is https://*SITENAME.COM*/administrator/index.php?option=com_creativecontactform&view=submissions

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Research "Joomla template overrides" to learn how to implement custom views correctly. You don't want to be modifying core or extension files, as your changes will be lost when you update.

Answer (score 2):

If I see it right, it's not a plugin, it's a component. I assume that you want to change the view, not the database table.

You should find all the files that handle the output of these components in the directory:

```
JOOMLA/administrator/components/com_creativecontactform/views/
```

or for frontend in the directory

```
JOOMLA/components/com_creativecontactform/views/
```

The file you're looking for should be in the directory

```
JOOMLA/administrator/components/com_creativecontactform/views/submissions
```

> Upate: You should not change the original files. If you like to change the output you have do create an override. See section **Component Output Types and Layout Overrides** in the Joomla documentation [Understanding Output Overrides](https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides).

Comment: You seem to be suggesting direct edits to component files. This is a bad idea for maintenance, as changes will be overwritten when the component is updated. Instead, use template overrides.

Comment: @isherwood Of course you are completely right. One should in Joomla! NEVER change files directly, but always override. I have only answered the question where the file can be found.

But you are right. I should have pointed that out in my answer.